# Show that $[A,\exp(B)]=\exp(B)[A,B]$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Denote $\exp(A)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{A^n}{n!}$ where $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$
>   and $[A,B]=AB-BA$
>
> Assume that $A,B$ commute with $[A,B]=AB-BA$
>
> Show that $$[A,\exp(B)]=\exp(B)[A,B]$$

I tried to use the fact that
$$
[ A^k,  B ] = A^{k-1} [ A, B ] + A^{k-2} [A, B ] A + \cdots + A [ A, B ] A^{k-2} + [A, B] A^{k-1}
$$

But I don't see how can I continue.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This does not sound right. Are you sure you have written the problem statement correctly?

Comment: @user1551 Thanks, I edited.

Comment: Comment to the question formulation (v2): It is not necessary to assume that $A$ commutes with $[A,B]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $B$ commutes with $[A,B]$, then $[A,B^k] = [A,B] B^{k-1} + B [A,B] B^{k-2} + \ldots + B^{k-1} [A,B] = k B^{k-1} [A,B]$ for $k  > 1$.  Divide by $k!$ and sum...

Comment: ... and more generally, if $B$ commutes with $[A,B]$, then $[A, f(B)] = f'(B) [A,B]$ (in the holomorphic functional calculus) for any function $f$ analytic in a neighbourhood of the spectrum of $B$.